# How to use json_tuple to parse all elements in an JSON object where you don't know the name of the key? (Hive)

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am parsing data from an API which returns data about products in JSON format. I have a Hive table `json_message_table` where I have each JSON message in a row of the table. I want to populate my Hive tables with this information and need to break down the JSON structure.

The structure looks like this.

```
  {product_name : ... , meta : { product_structure : { sub_product_1 : {...},sub_product_2 : { ... } ... }}
```

What I have done before in similar cases is

```
 SELECT b1.product_name as ProductName,
        b3.product_structure as ProductStructure
        FROM json_message_table a
        LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(a.messages,'product_name') b1 as product_name
        LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(a.messages,'meta') b2 as meta
        LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(b2.meta,'product_structure') b3 as product_structure;
```

My problem is that the name of the key `sub_product_1,sub_product_2` are different for each JSON object they can be called anything, so I can't specify what they will be called and thus do not understand how to use `LATERAL VIEW` and `json_tuple` to parse them.

What I want is to parse every field inside product_structure JSON regardless of the key name and then continue parsing the meta data inside their respective JSON. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can't do it without knowing column names and structure of JSON in advance